# Can I upgrade OpenSSL version used by apache without recompiling the server but just mod_ssl?

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl, mod-ssl

I have an Apache server on a Unix machine:

`Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/0.9.8zg`

I would like to upgrade the OpenSSL version to 1.0.2, which is the version currently installed on my system:

```
machine:/ user$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

Can I do that without recompiling the whole server? Do I have to recompile `mod_ssl` only as it is loaded inside `httpd.conf` with `LoadModule`?:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

The `mod_ssl.so` library is dynamically linked to OpenSSL:

```
$ ldd mod_ssl.so | egrep 'lib(ssl|crypto)'
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f23f7209000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f23f6e26000)
```

As long as your upgrade of OpenSSL does not change the path to the library, all you need to do is upgrade OpenSSL, and then restart Apache so that the new OpenSSL library is loaded. The last time that OpenSSL changed the library paths was in 1.0.0, I believe, so if you are updating from 1.0.0 or later, it should be fine. If you are upgrading from an older version (e.g. 0.9.8), you will need to rebuild mod_ssl after rebuilding OpenSSL.

Comment: Years ago, I tried to upgrade *libssl* from 0.9.7 to 0.9.8 IIRC. The filename has changed, so I symlinked it to the old one. This, however, failed completely, probably due to an API change. I can't tell if there's such a change after 1.0.0, but if the OP upgrades OpenSSL to improve security, I'd recommend upgrading httpd to 2.4 anyway, as there are important security enhancements - search for *Logjam* and *Diffie-Hellman Groups* with Apache 2.2. To have it fixed in 2.2, patching is needed (and so recompilation).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest upgrading your distribution, both Apache 2.2 and OpenSSL 0.9 are VERY, VERY, VERY old and hardly supported any longer.

If that is not an option, you will need to install dev headers for your installed OpenSSL version and recompile `mod_ssl` against them. That is, if you are using Gentoo or other "do it yourself" kind of distro.

Else, just man up and upgrade. It is LONG overdue in your case.