# Repairing Apache after OpenSSL update

Tags: httpd, openssl, apache2, mod-ssl

I made an OpenSSL upgrade on ubuntu server (14.04 LTS) via apt to 1.1.0f. After the upgrade was finished, I tried to (re)start apache2. Then this appears:

```
 * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
 *
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: symbol X509_getm_notAfter, version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

But the error.log was empty from the time after the OpenSSL upgrade.

What is causing the error and how do I solve it?

Comment: `apt-get install --only-upgrade apache2`

Answer (score 1):

There is old [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/721867/can-i-upgrade-openssl-version-used-by-apache-without-recompiling-the-server-but) about updating OpenSSL without updating Apache. You should update your Apache2 after OpenSSL update.